# How to fix If statement issue in c#?

Tags: c#, if-statement

First things first, I am an absolute beginner to c# so excuse me for any dumb mistakes I have done.
currently, I am making a "banking system" as my beginner project. I am getting a frustrating error
with entering a key.

```
           var input = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadKey());

           if (input == "E") {
               Console.WriteLine("English has been selected");
           }
           if (input == "A")
           {
               Console.WriteLine("تم اختيار اللغة العربية");
           }
           else {
               Console.WriteLine("Error!");
           }
```

if I input E or A the console only displays the Else condition instead of the two if conditions. side note: vscode doesn't show any errors relating to this.

Comment: Console.ReadKey() does not return a char as you are assuming, see documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=net-6.0)
consider adding an else before the secondo test: if input == "E", input=="A" will be false

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn about debugging and how to inspect the value of `input` at runtime.

Comment: you, probably, want `else if (input == "A")`, please, note `else if` instead of just `if`

Comment: Before `if` statements insert `Console.WriteLine(input);` and see what your input is.

Comment: When you do `Convert.ToString` and pass it a `ConsoleKeyInfo` (that's what `Console.ReadKey` returns), it becomes the string `"System.ConsoleKeyInfo"`, which you are then comparing to `"A"` or `"E"`.  This has nothing to do with the `if` statement.  I find it presumptuous of you to claim that it is an _if statement issue_, and it suggests to me that you didn't use your debugger to see what happened to `input` before you even got to your `if` statement.  `Console.WriteLine(input)` would have been educational too.

Answer (score 4):

In your code you are using `ReadKey()` - but you must be sure to use it properly. It's not quite as simple as say Python `input()` but C#'s `ReadKey()` does a good job once you understand it.

First, and most importantly, you need to know that `ReadKey()` does not just return a letter (like 'a', or 'b'), and it does not even return a numeric key code (like 9 or 10). Instead, it returns something called a `ConsoleKeyInfo`. Technically, it is a struct, but you can just think of it as "information about the key pressed".

Second, because your goal is to know what key was pressed and specifically if it was an `A` or `E`, you can get the `Key` property from the `ConsoleKeyInfo`. But once again, we are not getting a letter (like 'a' or 'b'), or strictly speaking an integer (like 9 or 10) - . The `Key` we get is an [Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/enums) or more specifically a [ConsoleKey Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolekey?view=net-6.0). So at this point we can either check the enum value directly, or convert it to a string representation and check it against a string value (such as "A" or "E").

Now, all of this can seem overkill for a tiny little program - but overall it provides a lot of benefit for writing safe and reliable programs. To compare it with something similar, it is like using a [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-6.0) object to represent a file, rather than just a using string for a filepath. But I do encourage you to read the docs referenced below because when you understand how to make use of documentation (and debugging tools) you have what you need to figure out most of this on your own!

#### tldr;

`ReadKey()` returns `ConsoleKeyInfo` struct, which we can use to get a Key property. Since the Key property returns an Enum, not a character or a string, we either check the value of the enum directly, or take one more step of calling ToString() on the [ConsoleKeyEnum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolekey?view=net-6.0) to convert it to a "letter" or "key" in string form. Additionally, the ConsoleKeyInfo class exposes a `KeyChar` property that may be used instead.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=net-6.0

#### sample revised code

```
var input = Console.ReadKey();

if (input.Key.ToString() == "E")
{
    Console.WriteLine("English has been selected");
}
else if (input.Key.ToString() == "A")
{
    Console.WriteLine("تم اختيار اللغة العربية");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error!");
}
```

Because we are working with Enums, it is really simpler and safest to use them in the comparisons directly:

```
var input = Console.ReadKey();

if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.E)
{
    Console.WriteLine("English has been selected");
}
else if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.A)
{
    Console.WriteLine("تم اختيار اللغة العربية");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error!");
}
```

Additionally we have the option to use the KeyChar property (this one does, however, return characters, not strings, and case matters - so we can get 'A', or 'a' depending on if shift is used or not).

```
var input = Console.ReadKey();

if (input.KeyChar == 'E' || input.KeyChar == 'e')
{
    Console.WriteLine("English has been selected");
}
else if (input.KeyChar == 'A' || input.KeyChar == 'a')
{
    Console.WriteLine("تم اختيار اللغة العربية");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error!");
}
```

Comment: Isn't it nicer to compare to the enum value, a la `input.Key == ConsoleKey.A` instead of relying on `ToString()`?

Comment: Yes, that is better. I'll update the answer. How much to say about a few little lines of code - but user inputs, and keyboards for that matter, are always a little more complicated than they may appear on the surface.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to simply use `Console.ReadLine()` instead of `Console.ReadKey()`. This will require the user to press enter after they have selected wither `A` or `E` but this is more user friendly when selecting an option as it gives you the chance to confirm your choice.

```
var input = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

if (string.Equals(input, "E", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    Console.WriteLine("English has been selected");
}
else if (string.Equals(input, "A", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    Console.WriteLine("تم اختيار اللغة العربية");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error!");
}
```

I also added a invariant string check to ignore case (so that "a" and "A" would both be accepted for example) and added a `else` to the second `if` statement as general improvements.

Note: Your use of `Console.ReadKey()` didn't work because it returns a struct that holds information about the input key - this struct will not convert into the original input key if you call `Convert.ToString()` on it.

If you do really prefer to use `Console.ReadKey()` then just access the input character using `Console.ReadKey().KeyChar`.

```
var input = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar);

if (string.Equals(input, "E", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    Console.WriteLine("English has been selected");
}
else if (string.Equals(input, "A", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    Console.WriteLine("تم اختيار اللغة العربية");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error!");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this please:

```
using System;

class Program 
{
    public static void Main (string[] args) 
    {
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        if (input == "E") 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("English has been selected");
        }
        else if (input == "A")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("تم اختيار اللغة العربية");
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See the first comment to the question - it applies here too *Console.ReadKey() does not return a char as you are assuming* - it returns a ConsoleKeyInfo struct :) Actually its a lot of complicated stuff for a little tiny program... !